# How Google protobuf RpcController work?

Tags: protocol-buffers, rpc

I would like to know the internals of how rpc mechanism in google protobuf works?

what does it use tcp or udp? what protocol does it use to communicate between remote machines?

Comment: `RpcController` is an abstract interface; it doesn't specify any protocol. Probably what you really mean to ask is how gRPC works?

Comment: yes. Please explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protobuf's `RpcController` is an abstract interface that could be implemented by multiple different RPC systems using a variety of protocols.

If you're specifically asking about gRPC -- Google's Protobuf-based RPC framework -- it sends RPCs as HTTP/2 requests/responses with Protobuf-encoded bodies, over TCP. You can read all about it on the [gRPC web site](http://www.grpc.io/).